# Summary Charts in Google Script from Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm new to Google scripting and have a very basic dashboard put together from all the information available online.  The source is a Google spreadsheet of data exported from a database.  I'm creating a Dashboard web app and would like to create summary charts on the dashboard due to the amount of information I'm working with.  I've contemplated using Pivot Tables but would then lose the functionality of the CategoryFilters.  I've seen lots of stuff about Google Visualization online and the Group function, but this doesn't seem to work in Google script.  Can anyone advise what to do? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "Dashboard web app".  Is this HTML?

Comment: I'm using script.google.com and creating a web app based on the instructions here https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/charts_dashboard

Answer (score 0):

Google give API for Google app script and Javascript.
It's really different because in app script you use a script in your google drive, and you use an app script editor.

If you use Google Vizualisation it's only javascript , you can deploy your javascript  application in google app engine for example.

Google vizualisation is very interesting  if you want to create a dataTable , a map , or others.

I use Google vizualisation for many charts because it's more simple and more dynamic  than google app script.

Comment: Thanks Hann.  I'm wondering whether Google app script is going to be too simple for what I require and I may have to learn how to use virtualization

Comment: yes , It's two different approach.  But Google Vizualisation is very interessting.
 https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery